# How do I make Angular Two Way Binding working here?

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

Can you help me to make it works, please?
The two-way binding is not getting/updating the values.
I would like that the values in app.component.ts were shown in app.component.html.
Thanks!

I will post the files:

**app.component.html:**

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <button type="button">Enviar</button><br>
    <label for="txt_usuario">Usuario:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txt_usuario" title="Usuário" size="10" [(ngModel)]="usuario"><br>
    <label for="txt_senha">Senha:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txt_senha" title="Senha" size="10" [(ngModel)]="senha"><br>
  </form>
  <span>Usuario: {{usuario}}</span><br>
  <span>Senha  : {{senha}}</span>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'teste';
  usuario: string = 'X';
  senha: string = '123';

  send(usuario: string, senha: string) {
    console.log(usuario);
    console.log(senha);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using it inside a form you can use formsModule for the two way data binding

```
<form #f="ngForm">
   <button type="button">Enviar</button><br>
   <label for="txt_usuario">Usuario:</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="txt_usuario" title="Usuario" size="10" name="usuario" ngModel #usuario="ngModel" ><br>
   <label for="txt_senha">Senha:</label>
   <input type="text" id="txt_senha" title="Senha" size="10" name="seha" ngModel #senha="ngModel"><br>
</form>
```

or if you want to make them standalone:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" #ctrl="ngModel" required><br>
<span>Other: {{ctrl.value}}</span>
```

I added a project so you can see this working:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdtdww?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Thanks Roberto, in your project it is working and I know that it works in many projects but I don't know why it is not working in my project. So I really need to know what and where I need to fix and what I need to include in my files to make it works.
I tryed to change the input line using **ngModel #usuario="ngModel"** but it don't solved the problem. This project was done creating a new angular project and only these files was edited.

Answer (score 0):

I found that was missing **name="usuario"** and **name="senha"** in the inputs, like below:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <button type="button">Enviar</button><br>
    <label for="txt_usuario">Usuario:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txt_usuario" title="Usuário" size="10" name="usuario" [(ngModel)]="usuario"><br>
    <label for="txt_senha">Senha:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txt_senha" title="Senha" size="10" name="senha" [(ngModel)]="senha"><br>
  </form>
  <span>Usuario: {{usuario}}</span><br>
  <span>Senha  : {{senha}}</span>
</div>
```

Doing this change started to work.
Thanks Roberto, looking your answer I found this missing definition.

Comment: that's what I was referring to use ngForms
`name="usuario" ngModel #usuario="ngModel"`. Glad it is working now :+1: